# Avoid undelivered mail returned to sender

Tags: webforms, emails

I have a webform that sends emails to the user who completes it. When the wrong email address is entered, I receive an email whose subject is *Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender*.

How can I avoid it? I don't see any parameter in the webform configuration.

Comment: You can't avoid that.

Comment: Really ? ... So I just can see my mail box being spammed by these messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Have to admit that I'm not familiair with webforms but is it possible that you send the e-mail from a noreply mail? This way you don't have to read the inbox of this mail address.

Comment: I try, in the settings of webform there is a field "Mail sender", I change it to my personal mail adress to make some test. When I complete the webform with a real mail I receive the confirmation sending my my adress mail (the good behavior) but when I complete with a wrong mail adress I don't receive anything and the webform send the "Undelivered mail ..." mail to the Webmaster adress and not mine.